# How to increase scrollable area of an ScrollViewer?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, scrollviewer

I am using an Canvas-Element within an ScrollViewer-Element.
Works just fine, but my problem is when some Objects are placed outside of the Canvas, i cannot "scroll to them" ..

If the Canvas is bigger then the ScrollViewer i can scroll, but not if there are just some objects out of the bounds from the canvas ..

is there any trick to increase the scrollable area?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The extent size (scrollable area) is, by default, derived from the size of the scroll viewer's immediate child.  When the extent size is computed this way, the only way to increase it is to increase the size of the child, e.g., your `Canvas`.

There is an alternate way to give more control over a `ScrollViewer`, and that is for the child element to implement `IScrollInfo`.  The `IScrollInfo` interface basically yields control of scrolling to you, including the viewport size and extent size.  However, if you go this route, you must implement *every aspect* of scrolling, including responding to scroll operations like `LineUp`, `LineDown`, `PageUp`, `PageDown`, `MouseWheelUp`, etc.  These are all exposed through `IScrollInfo`, so you don't have to worry about handling input events--just the logical commands.

Some cursory googling shows at least a handful of decent tutorials on implementing `IScrollInfo` if you choose to go that route.